# ios create popup like volume

Tags: ios, popup, volume

In my app I want to test connectivity, I want to make a little popup if there is no connectivity.

Is there a way to do a popup like the volume control? a square in the middle of the screen?

like this :
[image: exmple]
<sub>(source: [only-iphone.fr](http://www.only-iphone.fr/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/HUD-Controls-Plus.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [Adig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450896/adig) wrote, use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) or [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD). For checking the conectivity you can use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). *Just* combine them afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a couple of open source libraries to achieve this  : 
https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD
or 
https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD